# Remove duplicate words from a string

Tags: c#, string, text, duplicates

I need to remove duplicate words from a string. How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by duplicates.  Duplicate lines?

Comment: What do you mean by duplicates? Words? Sentences? Repeated characters?

Comment: You should also fix your tags and remove asp.net if it is not relevant to your question.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you want to remove the word "duplicates":

```
string duplicatesRemoved = RTBstring.Replace("duplicates", "");
```

;)

The easy (and overly simplistic) way to remove duplicate words is to split on the space character and use LINQ's Distinct() method:

```
string duplicatesRemoved = string.Join(" ", RTBstring.Split(' ').Distinct());
```

But this won't work in a useful way if you're working with actual sentences (i.e. punctuation will break it). Without a clear definition of what you mean by duplicates and what the expected input is, it's hard to give an accurate answer.

Comment: sweet thanks! i was using words so that works fine, next time i'll clarify better too :)

Comment: It's probably worth doing a search too - there are bound to be loads of answers to similar questions which go into much more detail than I've provided.