# How to remove repeated substrings from a string?

Tags: c#, string

How would you remove any repeated substrings from a string in c#? For example, in this string:

```
This is a test test string
```

The repeated " test" would be removed creating the result:

```
This is a test string
```

Or in

```
shift+shift+shift+shift+d
```

The "shift+shift+shift+" would be removed resulting in

```
shift+d
```

Comment: Sounds dangerous: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo

Comment: I assume you intend for + to be a string separator as well as a space?  Otherwise, would you want to turn "remove thee repeated substring" into "remove the repeated substring"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9424379

Comment: EDIT: @RobertHarvey beat me to it.
Sounds dangerously similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9424379/c-sharp-remove-duplicates-from-a-string

Comment: "This is a test test string" isn't `is` a repeated string too??? Must those string be clearly separated somehow?

Comment: @HansPassant: Thanks.  My head hurts now.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: This seems incompletely specified, but it does not look like a duplicate of [stackoverflow.com/q/9424379](stackoverflow.com/q/9424379). This questions asks for removal of repeated substrings ("abcabc xx abcabc" -> "abc x abc") while the other question asks for removal of duplicated words ("abcabc xx abcabc" -> "abcabc xx"). The solution in the other question (split().distinct().join()) will not work for this problem.

Comment: Its not constructive i think for eg "control+control+control+D" then what you expect "contrl+D" non repeated characters in string.?

Comment: This is indeed incompletely specified. Any repeating characters in a word will also be culled (indeed, culled would become culed). Do you want to specify word delimiters (e.g. space, plus, etc.)? Do you want to specify minimum length of a word?

Answer (score 0):

I hope that by your question itself by varying sentence repeated word are to be removed and word repeated characters are to be removed.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            var input = new[] {"This is TEST TEST string", "shift+shift+shift+D"};
            foreach (string data in input)
            {
                bool contains = data.Contains((char)0x20);
                Console.WriteLine(contains ? StripFromSentence(data.TrimEnd(new[] {(char) 0x20})) : StripFromWord(data));
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static string StripFromWord(string word)
        {
            char[] chr = word.ToCharArray();
            var ap = new HashSet<char>();
            foreach (char s in chr)
                ap.Add(s);
            return ap.Aggregate(string.Empty, (current, c) => current + c);
        }

        private static string StripFromSentence(string sentence)
        {
            string[] strings = sentence.Split(new[] {(char) 0x20});
            var ap = new HashSet<string>();
            foreach (string s in strings)
                ap.Add(s);
            return ap.Aggregate(string.Empty, (current, word) => current + (word + (char)0x20));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that out tommorow

Comment: This will transform 'test' to 'tes'.

Comment: obviously, don't see what i have comment if it is a word means it remove the repeated characters in the word. where as it is sentence means it will remove the repeated words based upon same case(upper and lower).