# Remove duplicates with conditions using ASP.NET Regex

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I am searching to remove duplicates in a document using Regex or something similar; to remove the following:

`First Line`

`<Important text /><Important text />Other random words`

I need to remove the duplicates of `<some text/>` and keep everything else remain as it is. The text may or may not be on multiple lines.

It will need to work off of several different words but use the < > tags.

EDIT:

I do not know what the words will be. Some will be nested inside < > tags and some will not be. I will need to remove all duplicates that repeat one after each other something like:

```
<text/><text/><words/><words/><words/>
```

And the output should be:

```
<text/><words/>
```

Comment: Could you go into slight more detail concerning what you mean by duplicates? Will thy always be one after the other or can it be anywhere else in the file? Will they always have the opening and closing tags as your example does??

Comment: Do you *know* the text you're looking for, or do you have to determine duplicates along the way?

Comment: Just check it out over [here][1] It's removing duplicate word from string.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9424379/remove-duplicate-words-from-a-string

Comment: What is the expected output for `<text/><text/><words/>XXXXX<words/><words/>` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Regex will search for duplicate tags, `(<.+?\/>)(?=\1)`, and here is a [Regex 101 to prove it](http://regex101.com/r/xN1gJ6).

Comment: Note that if you run this against `<text/><text/><words/><text/><words/>` will find matches for `<text/>` and `<text/><words/>`

Comment: Any idea how to modify this so that this works:

`<text>etc<text><text>` will return <text>etc

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
Regex.Replace(input, "(<Important text />)+", "<Important text />");
```

This will replace any instance of `<Important text />` repeated one or more times with a single instance of `<Important text />`.

Or more simply:

```
Regex.Replace(input, "(<Important text />)+", "$1");
```

For example:

```
var input = "<Important text /><Important text />Other random words";
var output = Regex.Replace(input, "(<Important text />)+", "$1");

Console.WriteLine(output); // <Important text />Other random words
```

---

If you'd like to handle multiple such patterns at once, you should use an alternation (`|`), specifying each word you'd like to handle, along with a back-reference (`\1`) to find repetition:

```
Regex.Replace(input, @"(<(?:Important text|Other text) />)\1+", "$1");
```

For example:

```
var input = "<text/><text/><words/><words/><words/>";
var output = Regex.Replace(input, @"(<(?:text|words)\s*/>)\1+", "$1");

Console.WriteLine(output); // <text/><words/>
```

Comment: I need it to work off several different words but look at the < > tags

Comment: @user1898471 What words are you trying to handle? Is it a fixed set? See my updated answer for a possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a dictionary of all tags, i.e. all text in between < and /> including the brackets, and their counts (this can be done with a regex). Then iterate through again, either removing duplicates or not outputting them to a new string/data structure.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I don't like Regex with tags.

Split the text on each tag, remove the duplicates with `Distinct`, join the result and voilà.

```
string input1 = "<Important text /><Important text />Other random words";
string input2 = "<text/><text/><words/><words/><words/>";

string result1 = RemoveDuplicateTags(input1); // "<Important text />Other random words"
string result2 = RemoveDuplicateTags(input2); // "<text/><words/>"

private string RemoveDuplicateTags(string input)
{
    IEnumerable<string> tagsOrRandomWords = input.Split('>');
    tagsOrRandomWords = tagsOrRandomWords.Distinct();

    return string.Join(">", tagsOrRandomWords);
}
```

Or if you prefer less readable one-liners :

```
private string RemoveDuplicateTags(string input)
{
    return string.Join(">", input.Split('>').Distinct());
}
```